# Php duplicate rows on join

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables. 
One is `products` and the other is `upload` where images are stored.

I'm try to get all detail for product by id from table `products`. In the same query, I'm trying to get all images from `upload` table where `upload.assign_product_id = products.id`. The query duplicating product detail for how image product I have but the image show OK. When I use `group by products.id`, the product detail is not duplicated but the images disappear, leaving only one image.

The sql query is:

```
SELECT * FROM products
JOIN upload
ON products.id = upload.assign_id
WHERE products.id=$pid
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's how it's supposed to work. you're doing a one-to-many join, so the fields on the "one" side will get "duplicated" for every matching record on the "many" side.

Comment: Show `uplaod` table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably in your upload table you have more than one image for every product. You can re-size the array after retrieving it where index id will be product. This way you can get one image for every product.

Thanks